# error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IXMLDOMDocument'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, gtk

I'm building a GTK+ VS2010 project configuration on (VS2013) and I'm  trying to add a browse folder functionality (I want to use Native Windows way). I'm using the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
DWORD WINAPI BrowseFolder(void *ptr)
{
    char path[MAX_PATH];

    cchar * path_param = (cchar*)ptr;
    BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };
    bi.lpszTitle = ("Select Folder");
    bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;
    bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc;//callback function defined..
    bi.lParam = (LPARAM)path_param;

    LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

    if (pidl != 0)
    {
        //get the name of the folder and put it in path
        SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);

        //free memory used
        IMalloc * imalloc = 0;
        if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&imalloc)))
        {
            imalloc->Free(pidl);
            imalloc->Release();
        }

        strcpy(g_sDefaultDir, path);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but when compiling I'm getting this error message

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\shobjidl.h(17624): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IXMLDOMDocument'

This is my configuration:
I'm running VS2010 solution on VS2013
Use Standard Windows Libraries
Not Using ATL
and Use Multi-Byte character set

Any ideas?

Comment: I also did try with different SDK's, v7.0A and Windows Kits 8.0 and 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 ways to answer solve my problem.

I had msxml and ISoftDistExt previously defined to solve ambiguity problem, so I had to #undef them like the following:

```
#undef __msxml_h__
#undef __ISoftDistExt_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
#include <MsXml.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
```

Also, you can use the #import statement like the follownig

```
#undef __msxml_h__
#undef __ISoftDistExt_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
#import <msxml6.dll> 
using namespace MSXML2;
#include <ShlObj.h>
```

Hope this will help someone later.